# SQL Access, Sum one column's values only when ALL values in another column in are in specified range

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have the following table (call it tblGifts) in an Access database (which is imported from an external source--and is frequently imported):

```
Person____GiftDate___GiftAmount  
 A________6/4/2014____$20  
 A________7/1/2014____$20  
 B________7/1/2014____$30  
 B________7/4/2014____$20
```

There is a user form that prompts the user for a date range. My hope is that I can sum the GiftAmount column only when ALL of the GiftDates are in the date range provided. So, for example, if the user gives 6/30/2014 to 7/10/2014, the output will be something like:

```
Person____GiftAmount  
 B________$50
```

Person A won't be included because he has a GiftDate outside of the range.

I was thinking of doing something like the following: (This obviously won't work because it pulls person A as well)

```
SELECT Person, Sum(GiftAmount)
FROM tblGifts 
WHERE GiftDate Between [Forms]![InputForm]![BeginDate] And [Forms]![InputForm]![EndDate]
GROUP BY Person
```

Comment: I'm not sure what access supports, but adding a subquery to your where clause that selects records outside the date range should work.  If access supports not exists, that's probably the way to go.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need to add a WHERE clause exclude the people who have donated outside the date range.

```
SELECT Person, Sum(GiftAmount)
FROM tblGifts 
WHERE Person NOT IN (
    SELECT Person FROM tblGifts
        WHERE GiftDate >  [Forms]![InputForm]![EndDate] 
            OR  GiftDate <  [Forms]![InputForm]![StartDate]
) 
GROUP BY Person
```

Comment: Ahh so simple! This is precisely what I was looking for thanks!

Comment: To avoid subqueries you could also do it with a left join but I'm not sure whether this is possible in MSAccess, or whether it would be more efficient. It would certainly be less readable.

Comment: While correct and intuitive, using not in tends to be slow.  If access supports not exists, that would be better.

Comment: @Hardik I was just thinking that the first condition isn't necessary. Think the last one is.

Comment: @Polly Shaw  I think if you will not write Not IN condtion then also this query will work fine. Am I right?

Comment: Joins are nearly always much faster than `Not In` in MS Access, but the OP may not have a large table or many indexes, so it may be irrelevant.